# Error al conectar mysql con python en docker

Tags: mysql, python, docker, flask

A la hora de insertar datos, python me arroja el siguiente error al conectar con mysql:
[image: Captura de pantalla de los mensajes de error]

El código es el siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask (__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'rojisDB'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = '3306'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/insert', methods = ['POST'])
def insert():
    if request.method == "POST":
        matricula = request.form['matricula']
        nombre = request.form['nombre']
        telefono = request.form['telefono']
        carrera = request.form['carrera']

        conexion = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conexion.cursor()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO estudiante (matricula, nombre, telefono, carrera) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (matricula, nombre, telefono, carrera))
        conexion.commit()
        conexion.close()
        return 'agregado'
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

A la hora de ejecutarlo en el contenedor:

[image: Captura de pantalla de código más salida]

Cuando inserto los datos desde la página web me arroja lo siguiente:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019 05:09:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/filesystem.py:63: BrokenFilesystemWarning: Detected a misconfigured UNIX filesystem: Will use UTF-8 as filesystem encoding instead of 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
  BrokenFilesystemWarning)
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019 05:10:05] "POST /insert HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/app/app.py", line 28, in insert
    conexion = mysql.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flaskext/mysql.py", line 53, in connect
    return pymysql.connect(**self.connect_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
    raise exc
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019 05:10:05] "GET /insert?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019 05:10:05] "GET /insert?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019 05:10:06] "GET /insert?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.17.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2019 05:10:06] "GET /insert?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

¿Alguna sugerencia o solución? Gracias.

Comment: ¿MySQL corre en el mismo contenedor o en otro diferente?

Comment: échale un ojo a esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145333/docker-cannot-connect-application-to-mysql

Comment: @OscarGarcia mysql esta de manera local (en mi maquina) e intento conectarme desde ella en el contenedor

Comment: @Borjinha10 Gracias viejo, le dare una leida

Comment: Debes poner el nombre de tu máquina en lugar de "localhost" para evitar que trate de conectarse a través del socket unix. En el caso de que corriera en otro contenedor entonces la respuesta de @Borjinha10 podría ser válida (sólo si corres docker swarm y tienes la configuración de servicios correcta).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Te refieres a la direccion de mi maquina? Si es asi, ya la cambie y sigue mostrandome el mismo error. Es la primera vez que uso docker y este error me esta mermando bastante jajaja

Comment: ¿Cómo has creado la imagen docker? ¿Estás usando servicios de docker swarm? Si estás usando una imagen independiente usa `--network="host"` para compartir la red con el equipo anfitrión y en vez de `localhost` usa `127.0.0.1` para forzar el uso de TCP. También puedes hacer un bind mount del socket unix de mysql. Depende de cómo crees la imagen docker debes usar `-v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld` o `volumes:`. Eso expondrá el directorio donde se guarda el socket unix del anfitrión al contenedor docker y, por lo tanto, podrá usar `localhost` como si se ejecutara en el anfitrión.

Comment: Te explico, me baje una imagen ubuntu, desde ahi comence a agregar algunas cosas que necesito (flask, wtform, python, wget, curl, nano, bootstrap). Antes de eso la ejecute de la siguiente manera "docker run -it -w /app -v //home/edgargc/docker:/app -p 8086:5000 edgargc/proyecto01:teco bash"

Comment: En ese caso puedes, por rendimiento, hacer lo que te propuse y agregar a esa línea el parámetro `-v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld`, donde `/var/run/mysqld` es el directorio donde tengas el socket unix de mysql (suele ser, en distribuciones debian/ubuntu, el archivo `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`).

Comment: Viejo, disculpa pero, con lo ultimo ya me enredaste, como deberia ejecutar el contenedor? Disculpa, soy nuevo, estudiante de informatica

Comment: Exactamente así: `docker run -it -w /app -v /home/edgargc/docker:/app -v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld -p 8086:5000 edgargc/proyecto01:teco bash`. Si te funciona házmelo saber para redactar una respuesta ampliando la explicación y con enlaces a la documentación.

Comment: @EdgarGc, ¿probaste lo que te propuse?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Disculpa viejo, apenas me vengo despertando, me quede dormido frente a la computadora. Cree el contenedor usando lo que me escribiste y funciona el contenedor. Ahora, cuando quiero intento acceder a la conexion me aparece otro error: OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)") (Pasamos del 99 al 111, ya es algo)

Comment: No debes mezclar mis recomendaciones. Usar `127.0.0.1` en vez de `localhost` es para cuando usas el parámetro [`--network="host"`](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/). Con el parámetro `-v` debes usar `localhost`. También puedes usar ambos parámetros (no son incompatibles) y probar ambas formas de conectarte (por conexión TCP y por socket Unix).

Comment: Se quedaría así: `docker run -it -w /app -net host -v /home/edgargc/docker:/app -v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld -p 8086:5000 edgargc/proyecto01:teco bash`

Comment: Al final no me dijiste si te funcionaron o no las soluciones que te propuse. PD: Cometí un error en mis dos últimos comentarios, era `--net host` y no `--network="host"` ni `-net host` (redacté desde el móvil de memoria sin poder comprobarlo), pero el de `-v` debió funcionar usando `localhost` (según tu mensaje de error cambiaste la dirección a `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: PD: No es necesario aumentar la complejidad de la infraestructura de red de docker como te proponen en la respuesta aceptada, ni apuntar a la IP externa del anfitrión (que podría cambiar en una red DHCP común), simplemente configurar adecuadamente el contenedor y decantarse por usar conexiones UNIX o TCP (o ambas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Dado que tienes una base de datos no contenerizada deberías **crear una red** que te permite conectar tus contenedores a tu red local y que esta solución funcione a largo plazo, dado que podría cambiar la ip de tu máquina al conectar en otra red.

```
$ ipconfig

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (External Virtual Network):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c542:1540:8737:c9cd%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 mynet
```

En tu código de ahora en adelante el host al que apuntarías debería ser **192.168.0.1**

Y al levantar el contenedor deberías ponerlo en esa red creada

```
docker run --rm --net=mynet nameimage
```

**2.** **Cambiar configuraciones** en tu base de datos para permitir conexiones externas, es decir mediante llamado de ip

Cambia la configuración de tu base de datos.

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

En el archivo de configuración comenta las siguientes líneas

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

Luego de esto reinicia tu servidor de MySQL

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

**Solución más sencilla**

Otra opción sería, sin crear red para tus contenedores simplemente apuntar directamente dentro del código que va a estar contenerizado a la ip de tu máquina, por ejemplo:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '192.168.1.3'
```

Comment: Herrrera estuve guiandome con lo que me explicaste y ahora me sale otro error (eso me alegra de cierta manera). Cambie algunas cosas, por ejemplo: bind-address = 0.0.0.0 Para que acepte todas las conexiones y monte mi contenedor en 172.19.0.1 (cree una nueva red).

Ahora el problema que me da es el siguiente:
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

Comment: Eso quiere decir que tu aplicación ya se está comunicando con la BDD.
El error que comentas es un error relacionado con el tipo de datos que estás intentando almacenar, puedes usar la función type() para chequear si coincide el tipo de datos que quieres almacenar, y la otra posibilidad es que algún dato se está perdiendo cuando lo recuperas via POST.

Comment: Oh ya. Viejo gracias. Ahora lo que me toca hacer es arreglar para llamar los datos en el codigo html.

Answer (score 2):

Docker te proporciona dos soluciones muy sencillas a tu problema:

- Montar el directorio del socket UNIX del servidor MySQL en tu contenedor.
- Compartir la red IP del anfitrión.

Al final de la respuesta extiendo algo más cada una de las dos opciones.

### Montar el directorio del socket UNIX del servidor MySQL en tu contenedor

Debes ejecutar tu contenedor usando el parámetro `-v` para exponer el directorio donde se guarda el socket UNIX al contenedor.

Para obtener la ruta al directorio puedes usar una de estas dos opciones:

**Búsqueda en los archivos de configuración:**

```
# grep -R socket /etc/mysql/
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Consultando al servidor MySQL:**

```
# mysql -p -BNe "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'socket'"
Enter password: (teclear la clave del usuario root de MySQL)
socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Comprobando los sockets utilizados por el proceso `mysqld`:**

```
# netstat -apln | grep /mysqld
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* ESCUCHAR xxxx/mysqld    
unix 2 [ ACC ] FLUJO ESCUCHANDO xxxx xxxx/mysqld /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

De las salidas deducimos que el directorio donde se guarda el socket UNIX de MySQL es `/var/run/mysqld/`, por lo que deberíamos ejecutar nuestro contenedor de la siguiente manera:

```
docker run -it -w /app \
  -v /home/edgargc/docker:/app \
  -v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld \
  -p 8086:5000 edgargc/proyecto01:teco bash
```

El código de conexión de tu aplicación no cambia, todo funcionaría tal y como lo tienes configurado actualmente:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
```

---

### Compartir la red del anfitrión

Para permitir que los procesos del contenedor se conecten a cualquier servicio IP como si se estuvieran ejecutando en el anfitrión basta con activar la red `host` en el contenedor haciendo uso de `--net host`.

Pero previamente debemos comprobar que el servidor MySQL esté aceptando conexiones TCP:

**Búsqueda en los archivos de configuración:**

```
# grep -R bind-address /etc/mysql/
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

**Consultando al servidor MySQL:**

```
# mysql -p -BNe "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'bind_address'"
Enter password: (teclear la clave del usuario root de MySQL)
* (nada)
* bind_address 127.0.0.1
* bind_address 0.0.0.0
```

En caso de que no devuelva resultados es probable que tenga el valor por defecto, `127.0.0.1`, de modo que deberemos usar la siguiente opción para asegurarnos.

**Comprobando los sockets utilizados por el proceso `mysqld`:**

```
# netstat -apln | grep /mysqld
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* ESCUCHAR xxxx/mysqld    
unix 2 [ ACC ] FLUJO ESCUCHANDO xxxx xxxx/mysqld /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

De las anteriores salidas observamos que el servidor está abriendo un socket TCP en el puerto `3306` que acepta conexiones únicamente desde `127.0.0.1` (localhost). Si estuviera escuchando en `0.0.0.0` (acepta conexiones desde el exterior) también valdría.

Por lo que deberíamos ejecutar nuestro contenedor de la siguiente manera:

```
docker run -it -w /app \
  -v /home/edgargc/docker:/app \
  --net host \
  -p 8086:5000 edgargc/proyecto01:teco bash
```

En este caso tu código necesita únicamente la siguiente modificación:

```
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

---

### Solución combinada

Puedes usar ambas soluciones y permitir al contenedor que se conecte mediante sockets UNIX o TCP usando:

```
docker run -it -w /app \
  -v /home/edgargc/docker:/app \
  -v /var/run/mysqld:/var/run/mysqld \
  --net host \
  -p 8086:5000 edgargc/proyecto01:teco bash
```

Con esta solución tu aplicación puede conectarse, de manera indiferente, a través de `localhost` (socket UNIX) o `127.0.0.1` (socket TCP).

---

### Detalles de cada solución (TL;DR)

- Montar el directorio del socket UNIX del servidor MySQL en tu contenedor:

  - Ventajas:

    - No requiere configuración alguna en el equipo anfitrión ni en la aplicación que corre en el contenedor.
    - El socket UNIX ofrece mayor rendimiento (latencia y ancho de banda) que el socket TCP. Por eso es el modo por defecto de conexión al servidor.
  - Desventajas:

    - Expones el socket UNIX del servidor MySQL a los procesos del contenedor, si están fuera de tu control podrían borrar dicho socket. En tu caso tanto el anfitrión como el contenedor está gestionado por ti, por lo que no es un problema.
- Compartir la red del anfitrión:

  - Ventajas:

    - No expones el socket UNIX al contenedor, por lo que no puede ser manipulado (borrado o sustituido).
    - No necesitas exponer el servidor MySQL al resto de la red con parámetros como `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` si no es realmente necesario.
    - Las aplicaciones del contenedor funcionan como si virtualmente se ejecutaran en el anfitrión, por lo que no se necesita exponer puertos con el parámetro `-p`.
  - Desventajas:

    - Debes asegurarte que tu aplicación se conecta a través de TCP en vez de intentar acceder al socket UNIX (comportamiento por defecto) usando como dirección del servidor `127.0.0.1` en vez de `localhost`.
    - Debes asegurarte que el servidor MySQL acepte conexiones TCP (por defecto suele estar así por defecto), agregando un paso adicional al proceso de configuración.
    - Si el contenedor no está bajo tu control podrían instalar un servidor web o cualquier servicio en puertos privilegiados (80, 443, etc) sin tu permiso.
    - El rendimiento de los sockets TCP es inferior al de los sockets UNIX.